# Which data structures and algorithms should I consider for a directed rooted tree that has high churn?

Tags: trees

I need to represent a directed rooted tree in memory.

**What would be a good data structure and algorithms for performing main actions, given the particulars listed below?**

- Size: ~40,000 nodes. But ideally should scale well to 10x the size or more.
- Arity: Very variable. Some nodes have 2-3 children. Some have 10. Some (rarer) have 1000.
- Data is NOT static - throughout the day, ~1-3% of the nodes/edges will be added/removed/moved to different parts of the tree (for a good real life example, let's pretend it's a filesystem tree where people are very active, and has symlinks).

**For the purposes of notation:**

- D(V) - depth of the vertex (distance from the root).
- A(V) - arity of the vertex (how many children it has).
- V - Size of the tree (how many total vertices)

**The following actions are needed** (with desired speed of action indicated).

- Ability to add a single vertex or a new subtree

  O(N) where N is the amount of vertices being ADDED (not already in the tree) and O(D(V)) where V is the vertex where new nodes are attached.
- Ability to delete a subtree

  O(N) where N is the amount of vertices being deleted and O(D(V)) where V is the vertex where new nodes are deleted from.
- Ability to move a subtree to another parent elsewhere in the tree

  O(N) where N is the amount of vertices being moved and O(D(V)) where V is the vertex where new nodes are moved between.

  *Note that due to retrieval needs described below, I do NOT anticipate that you can do this in O(1) independent of how many nodes are being moved, like in a regular basic tree data structure with child node pointers.*
- Ability to find a node by its name (needed for all the subsequent steps)

  Ideally, O(1). Most definitely much less than O(log V).
- Ability to know the full path up from the vertex to the root

  O(1) ideally. **But definitely less than O(D(V)).** This is very important; and is the reason why standard linked implementations of the tree won't work, even with 2-way links.

Comment: Other than the name lookup (which can be satisfied by putting all the nodes in a hashtable) this looks like a run-of-the-mill tree structure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - how can you do a less than O(D) path-up for a node in a regular tree structure? Wouldn't you have to cache the paths in some way? I agree that adding a hashtable would be one way to solve the name lookup (that's how I'm doing it now).

Comment: How deep is the tree likely to get?  Trees 20 deep can handle billions of nodes, if they're balanced, and a 20-depth traversal takes minimal time, unless, perhaps, you're doing string concatenation along the way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - the tree can get ~50 deep - and it's not terribly balanced. Also, finding a PATH implies concatenation, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, you either compute the path each time, or you store it for each node, I guess.  Is the path merely for display purposes, or do you do something high-performance with it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - yep, that's the choices I tried and both suck. I was trying to see if there's a more efficient, less obvious approach that smoothes the tradeoffs.

Comment: How many hops are you willing to make to get the path?  You could store 5 at a time... That would get you down to 10 hops in a 50 deep branch.  Is the problem the time it takes to concatenate?  What programming language are you using?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'm pretty language agnostic. Realistically would likely be Java or Perl or Python (current implementation is Sybase T-SQL, of all the fun things to maintain :))))

Comment: @ChrisF - this is NOT a duplicate. There are different tradeoffs and different data structures and algorithms for both cases (an ideal solution to the other question MAY answer this one, but IMHO due to tradeoffs that ideal solution would not exist). As such, an algorithm that ideally solves the linked question would most likely be sub-optimal for the tree one asked here  due to optimizing for properties actions and not tree actions.

Comment: This isn't the same question as the other one?  Does it involve the same problem?  I just figured you were asking a better question, but the way you do that is improve your existing one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - same problem domain, but would likely end up with different data structures (from past experience in the problem domain, the solution to the other one would strongly optimize towards the properties speed and be less optimal to pure tree side of it). It's possible that some approaches from this question may be helpful to solving another one however.

Comment: You could help the process by answering some of my other questions I asked here in the comments.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I thought I covered all of them except "store 5 at a time" and frankly I'm uncertain what you meant by that. Cache 5 immediate ancestors?

Comment: Yes, cache 5 immediate ancestors, and store a pointer to the fifth ancestor up (or something like that).  The problem, as I see it, is a simple tradeoff of storage versus computation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It might speed things up on retrieval of course, linearly. Question is what impact would it have on tree changes when you need to re-compute those caches (and know WHICH caches to recompute based on which tree nodes changed). That is precisely the sort of reasoning I was hoping to get in an answer :)

Comment: I really doubt there's a magic wand here.  If you need that fine of a control over the strings, you might look at something like a bloom filter, but I think the problem is more mundane than that.  Normally concatenated paths like that are required for display purposes, so I don't see what the need for speed is, even on a 50 deep tree.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'm not too familiar with that structure beyond skimming the Wiki article now, but how would it help here? I would think it would actually be more useful to my other question (because it does contain "is X in a set" questions on data that has a fairly large "standard" distribution and a smaller set of outliers)

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm just saying that if you can't afford to take the string concatenation hit, then you have to store the string instead.  I think that's what your problem boils down to, unless I've missed something.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - seems like an accurate assessment. I'm not saying a great solution exists, I'm saying I don't know enough about advanced tree algorithms to know for sure and hoping that some meaningful optimizations can be made, even if they aren't of magic wand variety. Hell I'll take linear optimizations :)

Comment: @DVK did you ever find a data structure?

Answer (score -1):

The long answer is, "The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 4A: Combinatorial Algorithms Part 1."

The shorter answer is, there are a whole bunch of different ways to do it. If you're not sure what representation to use, you're getting way ahead of yourself. The first question is, is there a way of implementing it in the language that you're using that you're comfortable with? Once you get that part nailed down and you have a working implementation, then you can worry about if it is optimized.

You don't want to be worrying about O() stuff at all unless you already learned two ways to do it, and you're choosing between them. If you want to learn how to analyze the different representations in advance and choose the perfect one, you really do have to read the book mentioned above. Each question you ask is a few dozen pages of dense mathematical explanation that builds on previous information in the book. You have to make it nearly 500 pages in, and then you'll know how to "generate all the trees," and you can determine which set of trees you want to optimize for.

Comment: Odd to see a delete request with no comment. Seems a bit silly. This is really the answer! You have to do an exhaustive survey of all the different binary algorithms if you want to optimize for some set of cases. This is discussed mathematically in the book that does that survey, mentioned above.

Answer (score -3):

As you said it is similar to a file system, why can't you actually use the Windows file system. Make each node an extentionless file (to save memory) and put them in folders. Once you index the locations, Windows will use the best possible algorithm to find the required subtrees (folders).

Using a hash table with double hashing with 1st function based on any 3-5 random digits of the name and 2nd based on all the rest of the characters.

Comment: Using Windows filesystem for a unix server would be a cute trick

Comment: I didn't know it was a unix server.

Comment: that's why when the question asks for data structures and algorithms, it asks for just that, and not specific implementation :)